# Error in config file : handler -Python logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Simple python which tries to write the log information using file config

```
import logging
import logging.config
import os

logging.config.fileConfig('Log_parameters.ini')

log_learn = logging.getLogger('sakthi')

def complex_algorithm(items):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        # do some complex algorithm computation
        log_learn.debug('%s iteration, item=%s', i, item)

k = [1,2,3]

complex_algorithm(k)
```

Log_parameters.ini I am setting the handler, formatter in config file.

```
[loggers]
keys = sakthi
[handlers]
keys = handle1
[formatters]
keys = simpleformatter

[logger_sakthi]
level = DEBUG
handlers = handle1
qualname = compiler.parser
propogate = 0

[logger_handle1]
class = FileHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = simpleformatter
args= ('Configg_log','w')

[formatter_simpleformatter]
format=F1 %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
datefmt  =
```

On execution, I get the below error, KeyError

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/M/PycharmProjects/LOGGING/Log_data_config_file.py", line 6,
>   in 
>       logging.config.fileConfig('Log_parameters.ini')   File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py",
>   line 79, in fileConfig
>       handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)   File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\logging\config.py",
>   line 134, in _install_handlers
>       section = cp["handler_%s" % hand]   File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\configparser.py",
>   line 958, in **getitem**
>       raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'handler_handle1'

Comment: which value of `datefmt` in config?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm struggling with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think,
`[logger_handle1]` should be `[handler_handle1]`

Answer (score 0):

handle1 is not a logger but a handler so as keys have been identified as -
[handlers]
keys = handle1

it will search with singular name --
so it should be handler_handle1
agree with @SkyOcean

other way --

if you want to add a new logger it self then add
[loggers]
keys = sakthi, handle1
and then logger_handle1 will work